# Authenticate using Google / MS Azure / LinkedIn / Box

Tags: vaadin, vaadin10, vaadin-flow

I'm new to Vaadin (but so far loving it). I'm using Vaadin 12, but am confused as to "best way" to implement a standard login screen using the "big main" external login systems, namely:

1. login with Google
2. login with MS Azure
3. login with LinkedIn
4. login with Box

(I do NOT intend to support a custom registration/login page to ask users their names & email etc -- it's a waste of time since users can pick from at least the above 4 supported systems, and this way I delegate the whole username/password management system to a far far bigger system etc.)

However, something as simple as a *stable/tested* login system using the "big" external providers (eg one of the above list) doesn't seem to be pre-built in Vaadin 12. (Nor were there any examples that I could emulate). The best I found was https://vaadin.com/directory/component/oauth2-popup-add-on/overview, but that seems to only work for Vaadin 7 (and maybe 8). And from past questions, my understanding is that Vaadin 8 components are not compatible with Vaadin 10/12/14 etc. So, how can one safely (and easily) implement a secure, simple login system with external provides (eg MS Azure) using Vaadin 12?

(Note: I did find https://vaadin.com/directory/component/google-sign-in-component/overview which appears to be for Vaadin 10+, but it only seems to work for Google; does that mean we need to custom-build similar components for MS Azure/LinkedIn etc by finding if someone has built a polymer web component for those systems and then integrating it into Vaadin? Even if the answer is "yes", it seems like the example from https://vaadin.com/directory/component/google-sign-in-component/overview  is "dangerous" (and btw, my web-knowledge and security knowledge is close to zero), since it seems to imply that one can simply use the "event" class to retrieve the user's name/email etc, but technically, shouldn't that info *NOT* come from the front-end (since any decent hacker could then directly call the Vaadin back-end servlet and simply "supply" a username/email etc), but instead *ONLY* the access token (or maybe it's called something else -- I'm fuzzy on the terms right now) and then the back-end code (and only the back-end code) would re-call the external provider (eg google) using this access token to then (and only then) finally determine the username/email etc. (And, since the back-end is java, I think the "best" such library to use is scribe: https://github.com/scribejava/scribejava/) (And presumably, once the username/email is finally determined, it can then be saved as a session variable in Vaadin somehow so that subsequent calls have the needed info?) (Note: As an additional constraint, I'm trying hard to avoid Spring -- I've used it in the past, and it complicates my code ten fold and makes debugging and integrating with non-Spring sample code a mild nightmare....I'm open, though, to use Java EE (ie javax libraries) if I must / if it's highly recommended to do so....)

Comment: That reads like a typical OAuth2 scenario. I would recommend reading the basics of OAuth2 and then use Spring Security (with Spring Boot it's even easier) to act as a OAuth2 client application. IMO Vaadin is not the framework that should do authentication things like "login with service XYZ" for you. However, you can implement the screen that delegates to the authorization server using Vaadin to replace the predefined one from Spring Security.